# Excel VBA Data Validation List error on line Range.Validation.Add Type:=xlvalidationList

Tags: excel, validation, vba

My problem arises once I try and call `MyRange.Validation.Add Type:= 3`. I keep getting the error 1004. I've scoured the internet and can't seem to find a solution to it.

My guess is that I have it formatted correctly but in a wrong location within my code for it to work? I'm really new two VBA (Last Friday), but it doesn't seem to be all to difficult (I know C++). I was just hoping someone with a bit more experience at it could point out the error.

Any Help is greatly appreciated. If my description of my problem is vague, please let me know what other information you need and I would be more than happy to post it.

Motor Sub:

```
Sub Motor(TotalLoad As Integer)

Dim Phase As Range, HP As Range, Voltage As Range, LoadType As Range, RatedkW As Range
Dim i As Integer 'Initializes the variables used.
Dim HPList(5) As String

For i = 4 To TotalLoad 'For loop that loops through till the value of TotalLoad

    Set LoadType = Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)) 'Sets the range for the "Load Type" Columns.
    Set Phase = Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)) 'Sets the range for the "Phase" Columns.
    Set HP = Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 7)) 'Sets the range for the "HP" Columns.
    Set Voltage = Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 8)) 'Sets the range for the "Voltage" Columns.
    Set RatedkW = Range(Cells(i, 9), Cells(i, 9)) 'Sets the range for the "Rated kW" Columns.

    If LoadType.Value = "Motor" Then 'If statement checking if "Motor" has be selected in the cell "Load Type".

        Call UnlockCell(Phase)

        If Phase.Value = "Single" Then

            Call UnlockCell(HP)
            Call UnlockCell(Voltage)
            Call UnlockCell(RatedkW)

            HP.Validation.Delete
            HP.Validation.Add Type:=3
            HP.Validation.Add Formula1:="list 1, list 2, list 3, list 4"

       'other codes-----------

    End If 'End of all the if statements.

Next i 'Increments the value of i within the for loop.

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, I also asked this question earlier today at mrexcel.com here is the link to it, but no one has responded yet and im trying to figure it out so i can actualy make progress on my code at work tomorrow. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/872934-excel-visual-basic-applications-data-validation-list-modifying-another-list.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out after deleting segment after segment of my code... The error was coming from my workbook being protected. I guess you cant create a list in vba in a protected workbook? and yes, i do have it set so that it allows macro changes and not user changes with my protection.

Just figured i would post my solution in case anyone else gets this same problem.

Thanks again for the help Paul!!

Here was the code that fixed my problem. The key was the unprotect, run code, protect again.

```
Unprotect ("PASSWORD")
With HP.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="""List 1"", ""List 2"""
End With
Protect Password:="PASSWORD", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
```